# Can't use Linq in Watch window when debugging a T4 template

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t4

I'm creating my own t4 template based of the T4 template created by EFF6.

The template is working fine.  I'm able to do to lots of linq queries with no issue.

The problem appears when I try to debug the template.  In my watch window, I keep getting errors like

```
'IEnumerable<NavigationProperty>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<NavigationProperty>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've made sure that my T4 includes

```
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs"#>
```